# How to access properties of a nested container using ID

Tags: javascript, user-interface, qml, containers, blackberry-10

I would like to access the properties of imageContainer outside of the ListItemComponent scope, for example when orientation changes, I have tried the following:

`imageContainer.imageHeight` it returns an undefined in the logs.

The portion of the code goes as follows:

```
ListItemComponent {
                                type: "item"
                                Container {
                                    id: listContainer
                                    layout: DockLayout {
                                    }
                                    preferredWidth: 180
                                    preferredHeight: 180

                                    ActivityIndicator {
                                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                                        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                                        id: myIndicator
                                        preferredWidth: 70
                                    }
                                    Container {
                                        id: webimageContainer
                                        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
                                        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
                                        preferredWidth: 200
                                        preferredHeight: 200
                                        ImageDownloader {
                                            id: imageContainer
                                            imageWidth: 170
                                            imageHeight: 170
                                            imageUrl: ListItemData.thumbnailPath
                                            onCloudImageUnavailable: {
                                                imageUrl = "asset:///images/ic_view_image.png";
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    onCreationCompleted: {
                                        if (parent.parent.dv_width == 720) {
                                            listContainer.preferredWidth = 160;
                                            listContainer.preferredHeight = 160;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where id imageContainer defined?

Comment: @rontornambe
It's defined in ImageDownloader 
id: imageContainer

Comment: I do not know much about Containers, but are you able to reference imageContainer from within ListItemComnponent?

Comment: yes I can do that, the issue comes when trying to use it outside of ListItemComnponent

Comment: Perhaps Container.imageContainer will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to root component, ListItemComponent in your case to access its nested items:

```js
ListItemComponent {
    id: listItemComponent
    property int imageContainerHeight: imageContainer.imageHeight
    ....
    ImageDownloader {
        id: imageContainer
    }
    ...
}
```

and so you can access this property from outside:

```js
console.log(listItemComponent.imageContainerHeight);
```